# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Web.Model.Appointment]' to type 'Web.Model.Appointment'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

This is a code fragment from my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cancel(string id,FormCollection collection)
{
   //This is how I would like to declare appt but I cannot seem to correctly pass id into this method
   //var appt = Application.Session.GetObjectFromOid<Appointment>(new ObjectId(id));

   //I am trying to do it this way instead but I get an error
   var appt = (Appointment)Application.Appointments.Where(a=>a.Id.Equals(collection["Id"]));
   .....
}
```

This is the error that I get:Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Web.Model.Appointment]' to type 'Web.Model.Appointment'.

This is my view:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="updateCancel(); return false;" /><button>Save</button>
```

and this is my function

```
 function updateCancel() {
    $('#cancel').ajaxSubmit({

    });
    }
```

So why am I getting this error?
OR is there a way to pass Model.Data.Id into my function so that I can just use id instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using and it worked.

```
var appt = Application.Session.GetObjectFromOid<Appointment>(new ObjectId(id));
```

Answer (score 14):

The Where-clause returns an iterator. Select what you want to use instead. I.e., if you expect only one result, you can use `FirstOrDefault`. You can also use an index, like `[1]`.

```
var appt = (Appointment)Application.Appointments.Where
     (a=>a.Id.Equals(collection["Id"]))
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` when the item is not found, so be sure to check the result value.

PS: you probably don't need your cast there. Without `(Appointment`, from the error in your title, this should just work, because the items in the list are of type `Appointment`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind when working with the LINQ operators--the ones that return zero or more elements, anyways--is that they return an object that can be assigned to IEnumerable.

- If you're expecting a single element, either you will need to append another LINQ operator. Single and SingleOrDefault both return a single result. These throw exceptions when there's MORE than 1 match.
- The First and FirstOrDefault LINQ operators also return a single element as well, just that insead of throwing an exception if there is more than 1 match, they merely return the first one found.

In either case if no match is found the "OrDefault" operators return a null, but the other two throw an exception.